# How can I get a value from a CheckBoxColumn using C# 3.0?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, lambda

I can get the current selected row in this way:

```
 private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){

//Cells[0] cause CheckBoxColumn is in that index (first column)
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell temp = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
}
```

So, Now I want to get all of the rows that have been checked by the user:

```
 foreach (var row_ in DataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().
                                        Select(o => o.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell>().
                                         Where(r => r.Value.Equals(true))).FirstOrDefault()){

}
```

I am getting `null reference` from the debugger.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're going about it wrong, and what you actually meant to write is this:

```
foreach (var row_ in
    DataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().
    Where(o => o.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell>().
    Any(r => r.Value.Equals(true))))
{

}
```

But I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer, Hopes helps (Thanks mquander for the .Any idea):

```
        foreach (var _row in dgvpendientepago.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().
            Where(o => o.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell>().
                Any(r => r.EditedFormattedValue.Equals(true))))
        {
          // do stuff like the following : 
          lst4Pay.Add(new Cobranzaciaseguro
          {
            numeroatencion = Convert.ToInt16(_row.Cells[3].Value),
            estado = 'P'
          });
        }
```